# unserialize(): Error at offset

Tags: php, serialization

I have a serialized array that looks like

$dec="Acetic Acid[1]=root&Ammonia[2]=root&Ammonium nitrate[3]=2&111[4]=root&Alcohol[5]=root&Bio plastic[6]=root&Black Powder[7]=root&Borax[8]=root&Bow[9]=root&Calcium Carbonate[10]=root&Calcium Hydroxide[11]=root&Anesthetic[12]=root&Calcium oxide[13]=root&Carbon Dioxide[14]=root&Carbon Nanotubes[15]=root&Casein[16]=root&Cellulose acetate[17]=root&Wood Gas[18]=root&pH [19]=root"

and when i try 
$arr = unserialize($dec);

I get error
 unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 373 bytes

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's not a valid serialized string, it looks like a query-string to me.

```
parse_str($dec,$arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: the response was from http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/ jquery plugin.

Comment: Very language has it's own 'serialize', PHP's one isn't javascript's one (or jQuery in this case), which is not anything like Python's or Java's one... The methods are named the same and have the same goal, but their actual structure is totally different.